# System.BadImageFormatException in VS2010 XAML-Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, xaml, designer

i use SQLite 1.0.79 (64 bit Setup over "sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x64-2010-1.0.79.0.exe")
in my project.
Binding the SQLite over GAC.
But in the XAML-Designer throw follow Exception:

```
    System.BadImageFormatException
    Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.79.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Es wurde versucht, eine Datei mit einem falschen Format zu laden.
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       bei System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       bei System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
       bei MS.Internal.Package.VSIsolationProviderService.RemoteReferenceProxy.VsReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.CachingReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ReflectionMetadataContext.Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.IReflectionResolver.GetRuntimeAssembly(Assembly reflectionAssembly)
       bei MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetRuntimeMetadata(Object reflectionMetadata)
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.d__c.MoveNext()
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.AttributeTableContainer.GetAttributes(Assembly assembly, Type attributeType, Func`2 reflectionMapper)
       bei MS.Internal.Metadata.ClrAssembly.GetAttributes(ITypeMetadata attributeType)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlAssembly.get_XmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings()
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensionImplementations.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata sourceAssembly)
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.Xaml.XamlExtensions.GetXmlNamespaceCompatibilityMappings(IAssemblyMetadata source)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.BuildSubsumption()
       bei MS.Internal.Design.Metadata.ReflectionProjectNode.SubsumingNamespace(Identifier identifier)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.BuildScope(PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.Markup.XmlElement.ConvertToXaml(XamlElement parent, PrefixScope parentScope, IParseContext context, IMarkupSourceProvider provider, Boolean visitCodeModel)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.FullParse(Boolean convertToXamlWithErrors)
       bei MS.Internal.Design.DocumentModel.DocumentTrees.Markup.XamlSourceDocument.get_RootItem()
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.Trees.ModifiableDocumentTree.get_ModifiableRootItem()
       bei Microsoft.Windows.Design.DocumentModel.MarkupDocumentManagerBase.get_LoadState()
       bei MS.Internal.Host.PersistenceSubsystem.Load()
       bei MS.Internal.Host.Designer.Load()
       bei MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.Load()
       bei MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedView.Load()
       bei MS.Internal.Designer.VSIsolatedDesigner.VSIsolatedDesignerFactory.Load(IsolatedView view)
       bei MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
       bei MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.BootstrapProxy.LoadDesigner(IsolatedDesignerFactory factory, IsolatedView view)
       bei MS.Internal.Host.Isolation.IsolatedDesigner.Load()
       bei MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView(Boolean isReload)
```

This Exception occurs on all Xaml-files.
But the program runs without error.

... EDIT ...
*I have edited, because I'm not even allowed to respond*

problem identified and resolved...

i had only installed the 64bit SQLite, but the VS2010 is a 32bit process.

Installing also the 32bit SQLite resolve the Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only installed the 64bit SQLite, but the VS2010 is a 32bit process.

Installing also the 32bit SQLite will resolve the Problem.

Comment: @MarioR At least I can answer for you